# Convert "['a','b','c']" to ['a','b','c'] : Javascript

Tags: javascript

Which would be best way to do these things?

**Note:** My array contains complex values means comma separated or object values in side string array  & Arrays string quoted in **double** quotes and elements are in **single** quotes.

**EX.** `str = "['sam', 'admin', '1062', 'Sam', 'True', '$$global_permissions#1062:manage_replenishment,purchase_order,reprint_invoice#1008', 'sameer@opnce.com', '9920580', 'en', '358', '{\"Sales-tax-details\":\"brand,category,supplierNo\",\"invoice-logs\":\"invoiceNo,eventDateTime,event\"}']"`

Here i played with `JSON.parse`,

```
JSON.parse(str);
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' // this error i got on console
```

Then i tried,

```
JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'))
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S  // this error i got on console
```

One more thing i wanted to explore here as,
if `str` contains following elements,

`str = "['sam', 'admin', '1062', 'Sam', 'True', '$$global_permissions#1062:manage_replenishment,purchase_order,reprint_invoice#1008', 'sameer@opnce.com', '9920580', 'en', '358', '{}']"`

for this `str` i tried,

```
JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

Its working fine here,

Regards.

Comment: Are they all in JSON format?

Comment: @EmilVikström: Yes, this is in JSON format even though JSON.parse not working.

Comment: In what way does `JSON.parse` not work?

Comment: @DonalFellows: For above mentioned example

Comment: “It does not work” is not helpful. How does it not work? What is the error message? What did you get and what did you expect instead? (Don't reply to me; edit your question to add that information…)

Comment: @DonalFellows:Have look at question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
JSON.parse('["a", "b", "c"]');
```

**EDIT**: For the **EX.** `str` from the question, the following should work:

```
JSON.parse(str.replace(/'{/g, "{").replace(/}'/g, "}").replace(/'/g, "\"").replace(/\\\"/g, "'"))
```

Comment: @Niks: your input structure is quite irregular. E.g., the string literal starting with `'$$global_permissions#1062` and ending with  `reprint_invoice#1008` has no closing quote. I believe I have a solution once this is fixed.

Comment: Sorry, i corrected my above example, Would be great if you share your solution with us.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
JSON.parse('["a","b","c"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` should work. If you can't use `JSON`, this also works:

```
var str = '["a","b","c"]'
   ,str2arr = str.replace(/"|\[|\]/g,'').split(',');
//=> str2arr = ['a','b','c']
```

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way would be:

```
try{
    var res = JSON.parse(your_string);
} catch(e){
    //console.log(e);
}
```

That way, in case if string is incorrect it will not produce error and also in catch block you can do right things for that case

Answer (score -2):

wihtout jquery (its not the question) try this:

```
var string = '["a","b","c"]';
var myArray = [];
try {
    myArray = eval(string);
}
catch (r) {
}

console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: thanks for you response but i d'not want to use eval because its evil in javascript

Comment: string a reserved word and not having the meaning of its content make your example valid please